# Luks - after suspended the password not match

Tags: 14.04, suspend, encryption

I have very big trouble. I have ubuntu 14.04 (standard instalation with full disc ecryption - luks). Yesterday I suspended my laptop and after few hours my laptop was discharged.

When I turned on my laptop then my password in the luks didn't work. I am 100% sure that this password is correct and my system locale is good. I checked also this password in the other ubuntu (live cd version 14.04) and I had the same problem (no key available with this passphrase).

I got this message on my console: No key available with this passphrase. I don't know

This is some logs from my computer:
Logs from cryptsetup repair is very strange because IMHO everything is ok.
How can I get proof that e.g header is broken or keyslot is broken?
what to do. Have I lost all my data? Please help me.

```
freeman@freeman:~$ sudo cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sda5
LUKS header information for /dev/sda5

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        512
MK digest:      60 88 7c 28 18 69 31 42 ce 4d 64 a0 20 9f f1 95 fb 03 e6 9b 
MK salt:        26 e8 60 b4 55 7b bd c6 8a 0c 2c 23 a3 9a 38 b2 
                cd 5a 77 7e 45 ba 68 e1 ae 52 ce 8c f9 e9 70 8c 
MK iterations:  35250
UUID:           d7431ab7-c761-4e7f-a1b9-5d7bc77f20cd

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
         Iterations:             140968
        Salt:                   3b 86 ac 53 70 70 1e 84 06 fc 7f 9b 16 bc ac 14 
                                 c0 6a 7f a6 18 10 3c 81 a7 9d d4 95 4d 3f 2a f8 
        Key material offset:    8
         AF stripes:             4000
 Key Slot 1: DISABLED
 Key Slot 2: DISABLED
 Key Slot 3: DISABLED
 Key Slot 4: DISABLED
 Key Slot 5: DISABLED
 Key Slot 6: DISABLED
 Key Slot 7: DISABLED
 Command successful.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 freeman@freeman:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen  /dev/sda5 aaa
 Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5: 
 No key available with this passphrase.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 # cryptsetup 1.4.3 processing "cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 test231 --debug"
 # Running command luksOpen.
 # Locking memory.
 # Allocating crypt device /dev/sda5 context.
 # Trying to open and read device /dev/sda5.
 # Initialising device-mapper backend, UDEV is enabled.
 # Detected dm-crypt version 1.12.1, dm-ioctl version 4.25.0.
 # Trying to load LUKS1 crypt type from device /dev/sda5.
 # Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.5.0) initialized.
 # Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device /dev/sda5
 # Timeout set to 0 miliseconds.
 # Password retry count set to 3.
 # Password verification disabled.
 # Iteration time set to 1000 miliseconds.
 # Activating volume test231 [keyslot -1] using [none] passphrase.
 # dm status test231  OF   [16384] (*1)
 # Interactive passphrase entry requested.
 Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5: 
 # Trying to open key slot 0 [ACTIVE_LAST].
 # Reading key slot 0 area.
 # DM-UUID is CRYPT-TEMP-temporary-cryptsetup-7649
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) created
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) incremented to 1
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) incremented to 2
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) assigned to CREATE task(0) with flags > > DISABLE_SUBSYSTEM_RULES DISABLE_DISK_RULES DISABLE_OTHER_RULES (0xe)
 # dm create temporary-cryptsetup-7649 CRYPT-TEMP-temporary-cryptsetup-7649 OF   [16384] (*1)
 # dm reload temporary-cryptsetup-7649  OFRW    [16384] (*1)
 # dm resume temporary-cryptsetup-7649  OFRW    [16384] (*1)
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649: Stacking NODE_ADD (252,0) 0:6 0660 [verify_udev]
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649: Stacking NODE_READ_AHEAD 256 (flags=1)
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) decremented to 1
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) waiting for zero
 # Udev cookie 0xd4de08b (semid 2818048) destroyed
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649: Processing NODE_ADD (252,0) 0:6 0660 [verify_udev]
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649: Processing NODE_READ_AHEAD 256 (flags=1)
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649 (252:0): read ahead is 256 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649 (252:0): Setting read ahead to 256

 # Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) created
 # Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) incremented to 1# Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) incremented to 2
 # Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) assigned to REMOVE task(2) with flags (0x0)
 # dm remove temporary-cryptsetup-7649  OFT    [16384] (*1)
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649: Stacking NODE_DEL [verify_udev]
 # Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) decremented to 1
 # Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) waiting for zero
 # Udev cookie 0xd4dcce0 (semid 2850816) destroyed
 # temporary-cryptsetup-7649: Processing NODE_DEL [verify_udev]
 # Trying to open key slot 1 [INACTIVE].
 # Trying to open key slot 2 [INACTIVE].
 # Trying to open key slot 3 [INACTIVE].
 # Trying to open key slot 4 [INACTIVE].
 # Trying to open key slot 5 [INACTIVE].
 # Trying to open key slot 6 [INACTIVE].
 # Trying to open key slot 7 [INACTIVE].
 No key available with this passphrase.
 # Interactive passphrase entry requested.
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup repair  /dev/sda5 --debug
 # cryptsetup 1.6.1 processing "cryptsetup repair /dev/sda5 --debug"
 # Running command repair.
 # Locking memory.
 # Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
 # Unblocking interruption on signal.
 # Allocating crypt device /dev/sda5 context.
 # Trying to open and read device /dev/sda5.
 # Initialising device-mapper backend library.
 # Trying to load LUKS1 crypt type from device /dev/sda5.
 # Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.5.3) initialized.
 # Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device /dev/sda5
 # Key length 64, device size 499615744 sectors, header size 4036 sectors. No known problems detected for LUKS header.
 # Releasing crypt device /dev/sda5 context.
 # Releasing device-mapper backend.
 # Unlocking memory. Command successful.
```

Comment: Perhaps some data got corrupted and this goes unnoticed to the cryptsetup tools. Perhaps your disk drive is failing (did you check SMART diagnostics?). Perhaps your keyboard is failing. Lessons for next time: 1) add an additional recovery passphrase/key 2) Backup the full LUKS header with master key and store it somewhere safe.